# how to inject service for 2 modules

Tags: angularjs

I have a project with 2 separate modules, `.module('app')` and `.module('secondApp')`. In `.module('app')` I have service for field validation. Now I need to add this service for second module too. Can I inject 1 service for 2 modules, or I need to duplcate this service for another module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a module 'MyServiceModule'.

In this module, add the service.

In the 2 modules that you wrote, add 'MyServiceModule' in requirement like this:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['MyServiceModule']);
```

full example:

```
angular.module('MyServiceModule', []).service(...);
angular.module('app1', ['MyServiceModule']);
angular.module('app2', ['MyServiceModule']);
```

In app1 and app2 you have access to any service, directive of MyServiceModule.

By doing that, you can share the service in any other of your project, even create a bower/npm package for your service.